# merging test results across different agent in the same pool

Tags: azure-devops

The yaml for the PublishTestResults@2 task allows mergeTestResults to be set to true, does this allow test results from multiple agents in the same pool to be merged ?. What I am after is the ability to run tests concurrently across multiple self hosted agents and then merge them together. I suspect you cannot run multiple agents on the same host unless each one is for a different Azure DevOps org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this allow test results from multiple agents in the same pool to
>   be merged ?

The short answer about this question is "No, it doesn't support". For [Merge test results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#arguments), it just merge all test result files into a single test run which under one build job.

For **build with multiple agents**, it will produce several builds which independent of each other. So, **Merge test result** could not merge all of result files which run with multiple agents into one test run.

In addition, if you purchase parallel job for your private project, you will get the feature of running builds/release with multiple agents on the same pool. And these agents do not need work for different Org.

Comment: Is there any way to run multiple build agents on the same Linux host ?, tried this but not having any success.

Comment: First, I need to say that it just support run with multiple agents which under one same pool. If your project is public and use Microsoft-hosted pool, it provide 10 free parallel job. But, if you use self hosted pool, it will depends on how many agents you configured in this pool, no limit. If your project is private, you may purchase for this or you will not use parallel, even with self hosted.

Comment: Think I know what my problem is, each agent needs to be downloaded into a different directory, I will try this - thanks for your help.